# Comment s'appelle cette "poignée" suspendue dans le métro ?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot, transports

En japonais ça s'appelle [つり革](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%A4%E3%82%8A%E9%9D%A9):

[image: つり革] [image: strap]

On la tient pour éviter d'être déséquilibré quand le métro/train/bus démarre/secoue/s'arrête.

In English it might or might not be called "hanging strap", "grab handle", "hanging strap", "suspended ring", "moveable strap".

Comment: Je ne connais pas de nom dédié à cet objet. Je pense que « poignée » est effectivement le terme générique à utiliser ici.

Comment: J'ai trouvé plusieurs références aux *"poignées de plafond"*, mais rien sur un terme spécifique. Google traduit le mot japonais par *sangle*.

Comment: J'ai toujours trouvé que ça ressemblait à une *dragonne*. J'ai un peu cherché mais apparemment ce n'est pas tout-à-fait ça, même si les formes et fonctions sont proches.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Une *dragonne* est faite pour maintenir un outil au poignets d'un humain lorsque la main le relâche ; une *poignée*, donne une prise à la main humaine pour agripper un objet qui peut être transportable ou fixé.

Comment: Fact: cette "poignée" est utilisée en tant que "dragonne de train" par Chuck Norris.

Answer (score 7):

*Une poignée*, le fait qu'elle soit à portée de main accrochée au plafond, fichée sur un montant ou sur une valise elle demeure une poignée.

À Paris, on rencontre ce genre de poignée dans les bus.

On aurait tendance à dire « une poignée accrochée au plafond », mais les agents des transports en communs disent lorsqu'elles existent : « Accrochez-vous aux poignées lorsque vous ne pouvez saisir les barres » (verticales, au dos des sièges, le long des portes, parfois au plafond dans les trains de banlieue ou du métro ...).

Comment: « Poignée » toute seule est surement la bonne réponse (+1), mais si l’on en ajutait « de maintien » [comme ici](http://ldr-rolltechnik.de/fr/poign%C3%A9e-de-maintien-avec-technologie-led.html) (d’accord c’est une traduction de l’allemande j’imagine et ça a l’aire de s’agir plutôt des barres), est-ce que « poignée de maintien » serait compris dans ce contexte ?  (ou peut-être c’est déjà trop lié avec les poignées fixes pour grimper/descendre [des baignoires, par exemple])

Comment: @PapaPoule Je préfère *"poignée de plafond"* personnellement.

Comment: @PapaPoule À  l'origine *le maintien* est l'art de se tenir correctement en société, pour se fondre dans le groupe et paraître à son avantage.Votre lien se réfère à une technique utilisée dans des situations peu ordinaires, elle pourrait tout aussi bien faire référence à une poignée spécifique à usage thérapeutique. Mais pour notre cas, cela fait tautologie, s'il n'y avait pas besoin de maintenir les personnes debout malgré les aléas du trajet, il n'y aurait pas de ces poignées... qui n'ont rien de spécial, ni par leur forme, ni par leur destination.

Comment: En résumé, il n'y a pas plus de traduction unique en fançais qu'il ne semble y avoir en Anglais. je me demande s'il y en a une en allemand tiens...

Comment: @PapaPoule Il serait bizarre que je me trompe, mais « ça à l'air de s'agir » ne se dit pas (TLFi : C. Emploi pronom. (impers.). S'agir.); vous préfèrerez peut-être vous assurer par vous-même; on ne trouve que des exemples avec *il* impersonnel dans ce dictionnaire. (et il me semble qu'il s'agisse plutôt des barres *ou* il s'agirait des barres que je ne serais pas surpris)

Answer (score 3):

En complément, comme on le dit dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14095), usuellement la « *poignée* » :

> [B.] 3. Sangle, anneau servant à se tenir (en particulier dans
>   certains véhicules). *Tenez-vous aux barres et aux poignées!*
>
> [ Trésor de la langue française informatisé (TLFi) - « [*poignée*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poign%C3%A9e)
>   » ]

Et donc avec la *sangle* et l'*anneau*, on rend généralement ce qu'on décrit dans la question. Mais rien n'empêche que des termes techniques existent concurremment et soient utiles quand il s'agit de décrire de manière nuancée ce matériel à l'extérieur du cadre de l'expérience du transport en commun en soi.

---

[En effet](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14094/comment-sappelle-cette-poign%C3%A9e-suspendue-dans-le-m%C3%A9tro#comment26647_14095), la « [*poignée de maintien*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8373044) » réfère d'abord à la poignée rigide qu'on peut utiliser pour s'aider à entrer ou sortir d'un *véhicule*; c'est souvent fixé [latéralement](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=GRAB%20STRAP) (« *assist grip* », « *hand hold* », « *assist handle* ») ou à même la portière. En *aéronautique*, on trouve aussi des [termes](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=9482934) pour « *grab handle* » : « *poignée d'assistance/de retenue/de maintien* »; aussi, différemment, en *transport routier*, la « [*poignée montoir*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2076715) ».<sup>1</sup> Au final on peut élaborer au besoin le très « descriptif » :

> Une poignée de maintien avec bande synthétique en forme de boucle (fixée à une barre horizontale (à l'aide d'un collier de positionnement)).

...ce qui permet de traiter de la *forme* de la poignée en question.

---

<sub>1. J'ai noté un cas où [une société](http://www.faigle.be/produits-et-solutions/solutions-de-branche/transports-en-commun/igostrap-halteschlaufen.aspx) utilise « *poignée de maintien* » pour décrire exactement ce qu'on présente dans la partie droite de l'image  : « *poignées de maintien ergonomiques en matière synthétique [...] la bande de la poignée [...] Même après de nombreuses années, ces poignées en matière synthétique forment toujours la boucle voulue [...] Le collier de positionnement...* ». Peu importe le terme, c'est peu étayé vu l'emploi usuel de la *poignée*. Cependant, un document de la [législation française](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do;jsessionid=7F0F8CA05DCDE5D23A51D4DEC0947BF1.tpdila13v_2?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000020742453&dateTexte=20150615) fait état de l'emploi des *poignées* généralement et des *poignées de maintien* (en plus des : *barres/barres de maintien*, *rambardes*, *sangles*, *mains courantes* etc., art. 5,6, et 35 entres autres). Mais c'est utilisé de manière plus abstraite, et plusieurs dispositifs peuvent avoir des formes différentes malgré un même fonction, et tous ne sont fixés à une barre horizontale, etc..</sub>

Comment: Qu’est qu’elles sont belles ces poignées en couleur de macaron chez [Ladurée](http://www.gilt.com/brand/acc-distribution/product/1095381378-acc-distribution-laduree-macarons?utm_source=google&utm_medium=CPC&utm_campaign=PLA&gclid=CJWBp8KdksYCFY-QHwodxycAsQ)! En tout cas c’est peut-être vrai que 'poignée de maintien' n’est pas forcement bcp plus redondant que 'ceinture de sécurité' et parfois l'ajute d’un p’tit brin de redondance sert à nous rappeler à quoi une chose sert et de l’importance de l’utiliser comme conçue. Thanks!